# Can I merge arrays which names are kept as variable?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array that contains names of arrays

```
$names_array[] = ('$array1', '$array2', $array3'....)
```

The `$names_array[]` is dynamically updated so it may contain 2 or more different names.

When the script is executed the values of listed arrays in `$names_array[]` need to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

I think in case of merging it is not a problem

u can merge $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$names_array = array ('array1', 'array2', 'array3');

$array1 = array ('a','b','c');
$array2 = array ('d','e','f');
$array3 = array ('g','h','i');

$result = array ();
foreach ($names_array as $x) {
    $result = array_merge ($result, $$x);
}

print_r ($result);
```

Comment: Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: I edited my answer to show the correct answer without the '$' sign

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done with variable variables.

```
$arraymerge = array();
foreach ($names_array as $arrayname)
    {
    $arraymerge = array_merge($arraymerge, ${$arrayname});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help... I have went around the problem: if anyone needs to merge dynamically generated arrays, in my case I have six arrays that exist or not, so I need to merge the existing ones. What I did is:

```
if(!is_array($array1[$i])) $array1[$i]=array();
if(!is_array($array2[$i])) $array2[$i]=array();
if(!is_array($array3[$i])) $array3[$i]=array();
if(!is_array($array4[$i])) $array4[$i]=array();
if(!is_array($array5[$i])) $array5[$i]=array();
if(!is_array($array6[$i])) $array5[$i]=array();

$combineddata[$i]=array_merge($array1[$i], $array2[$i],$array3[$i],$array4[$i], $array5[$i], $array6[$i]);
```

In case 'array_x[$i]' doesn't exists array_merge doesn't break the script just merges empty array.

Thanks